# Percorrer um .map () em dentro de .map () React jsx

Tags: react, typescript, jsx, next.js

Estou usando o React com TypeScript.
É possível ir array que está dentro de um array?
Este é o meu array:

```
const menu: Array<{name: string; to: string; icon?: ReactNode; submenu?: any}> = [
            {
                name: 'Segmento', to: '/', icon: Label,
                submenu: [
                    { name: 'Segmento 1', to: '/Segmento_1', icon: Label }, { name: 'Segmento 2', to: '/', icon: Label },
                    { name: 'Segmento 1', to: '/Segmento_1', icon: Label }, { name: 'Segmento 2', to: '/', icon: Label },
                ],
            },
        ]
```

Estou fazendo assim para percorrer...

```
export default function MenuTreeView() {

   const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <TreeView
            className={classes.root}
            defaultExpanded={['']}
            defaultCollapseIcon={< ArrowDropDownIcon />}
            defaultExpandIcon={< ArrowRightIcon />}
            defaultEndIcon={< div style={{ width: 24 }} />}
        >
            {menu.map((item, index) => (
                <StyledTreeItem nodeId={index} labelText={item.name} labelIcon={item.icon} />
                item.submenu.map((subitem, subindex) => (
                    <StyledTreeItem
                        nodeId={subndex}
                        labelText={subitem.name}
                        labelIcon={subitem.icon}
                    /> 
                ))
                </StyledTreeItem >
            ))}
        </TreeView >
    );
 }
```

mas da erro de compilação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa colocar o segundo map dentro de chaves também, visto que ele estrá dentro de um elemento JSX.

**Edit**
Vale notar que o elemento StyledTreeItem está sendo fechado duas vezes, remova a self closing tag desse elemento.

```js
export default function MenuTreeView() {

   const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <TreeView
            className={classes.root}
            defaultExpanded={['']}
            defaultCollapseIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}
            defaultExpandIcon={<ArrowRightIcon />}
            defaultEndIcon={<div style={{ width: 24 }} />}
        >
            {
                menu.map((item, index) => (
                    <StyledTreeItem nodeId={index} labelText={item.name} labelIcon={item.icon}>
                        {
                            item.submenu.map((subitem, subindex) => (
                                <StyledTreeItem
                                    nodeId={subndex}
                                    labelText={subitem.name}
                                    labelIcon={subitem.icon}
                                /> 
                            ))
                        }
                    </StyledTreeItem>
                ))
            }
        </TreeView>
    );
 }
```